# php+jquery+captcha, is this is the correct way?

Tags: php, jquery, captcha

I am using combination of php+jQuery for captcha validation and later sending mails and do other stuff. The pseudo code is something like this:

```
captcha_code = jQuery.post(.....execute captcha script and get status)
if(captcha_code == "correct"){
    send_mail_using_php_script;
}
```

Now I have no idea whether spammers can directly execute the "send_mail_using_php_script". Do they? If yes, then shall I move captcha validation in send_mail_using_php_script to make it more safer? Is there any other safer method?

Prashant

Comment: If you used a pre-packaged captcha solution, wouldn't there be an example on how to do this? Which captcha are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The validation should be done server side. While security through obscurity works ok against spam bots, anything on the client is fair game.

And a captcha "validated" on the client side defeats the purpose.

Comment: I am using a custom captcha script. What do you mean by server side? I am new to web programming so please have some patience with me.

Comment: By server side I mean, in this case, the PHP handler. The script that sends the mail should not run unless a valid captcha response was submitted. The first rule of web development is: don't trust user input.

If you validate on the client side, in javascript, theres not much stopping someone from tweaking the code and turning you into a spam dispenser.

Answer (score 0):

Important for Captcha is that validation takes place on the server.
That's the most important part to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You're validating the actual captcha at the server side, but you're validating the result and instructing to send the mail in the client side. This is wrong. JavaScript/jQuery runs at the client machine and can be modified by the enduser the way s/he like. The enduser can for instance remove the `if` statement or make it always evaluate `true` and reexecute the code.

You need to instruct to send the mail at the server side, during processing of the form submit.

Comment: Ok, What if I move the captcha validation inside "send_mail_using_php_script". I'll pass the captcha code entered in the input and the email address to script. First script will validate captcha and if it's correct then send a mail. I think this way both the things are happening at server side. Am I correct?